# How can I custom an editable container panel control in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to custom an editable container panel control like below in wpf.

[image]

The container panel control is an parent control that chould contains any other control and it is an editable control.It displays a plus icon with blank space when the panel control did not contain any control.User could click the panel which displays a plus icon to add any control to the panel.User could remove the control by floating bar which contains in the panel control.

Is there anybody could tell me what the name of this kind of control panel?And how can I achieve it in wpf?Any clue?

Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Try take alook at [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),It should helps.